# Copying Django project to root server is not working

Tags: python, django, deployment

I hope you can help me.

I have been building this webshop for the company I work for with Django and Lightning Fast Shop.

It's basically finished now and I have been running it of a virtual ubuntu machine on my PC. Since it got annoying leaving my PC on the entire time, so others could access the site, I wanted to deploy it on a root server. So I got a JiffyBox and installed ubuntu on it.

I managed to get Gnome working on it and to connect to it with VNC. I then uploaded my finished project via FTP to the server.

Now I thought I would only need to download Django-LFS, create a new project and replace the project files with my finished ones.

This worked when I tested it on my virtual machine.

To my disappointment it did not work on the root server. When I tried running "bin/django runserver" I got an error message saying "bash: bin/django: Permission denied" and when I try it with 'sudo' I get "sudo: bin/django: command not found"

I then realized that I had downloaded a newer version of Django-LFS and tried it with the same version to no avail.

I am starting to get really frustrated and would appreciate it very much if somebody could help me with my problem.

Greetings, Krytos.

Comment: Why in the world are you running `bin/django runserver`? Has this ever worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what a "root" server is. But you don't deploy Django by just copying the files: you need to configure the webserver. The documentation has a very [comprehensive explanation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/).

Answer (score 0):

I know some of this tip can be obvious but never knows:

- Do you update all your settings in settings.py ? (paths to static files, path to project...)
- Wich server are you using ? django server ? apache ? nginx ?
- **Do you have permissions over all file in the project ?** You should check that the **owner of the files is the user** you have, **not root**. If the owner is root you'll have this permissions problem in every file that is owned by root.
- Are you using uwsgi ?
- Have you installed all the apps you got in your VM ?
- Have you installed the SAME version you got in your VM ?

When I move a project from VM to real server I go over this steps:

- Review settings.py and update paths
- Check permissions in the folder that the web server may use
- I have a list with the packages and versions in a txt file, let's call it `packages.txt`
- I install all that packages using `pip install -r packages.txt`
- I allways use apache/nginx, so I have to update the virtualhost to the new paths
- If I'm using uwsgi, update uwsgi settings

To downgrade some pip packages you may need to delete the `egg` files, because if you uninstall a package and reinstall it, although your using `pip install package==VERSION`, if you have a package already downloaded, pip will install this one, even if the VERSION is different.

To check actual version of pip packages use `pip freeze`

To export all pip packages to a file, to import them in other place: `pip freeze > packages.txt` nad to install packages from this file `pip install -r packages.txt`